# Smalltalk Array Types

Tags: arrays, smalltalk, squeak

When looking at Smalltalk syntax definitions I noticed a few different notations for arrays:

```
#[] "ByteArray"
#() "Literal Array"
{}  "Array"
```

- Why are there different array types? In other programming languages I know there's only one kind of array independent of the stored type.
- When to choose which kind?
- Why do literal array and array have a different notation but same class?

Comment: Note that the `#[]` syntax is not supported in every Smalltalk dialect.

Comment: Nor is the `{}` syntax supported in all Smalltalks.

Comment: Smalltalk is not the only language either. Python supports literal lists (e.g. `['one', 'two', 'three']`) as well as literal byte arrays (e.g. `b'\x60\x0D\xF0\x0D'`)

Comment: The `{ }` was created in Squeak Smalltalk, and is most dependable in Squeak and its derivatives, Pharo and Cuis.  It is not available in, for example, Dolphin Smalltalk.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a little walkthrough:

Firstly, we can find out the types resp. classes of the resulting objects:

- `#[] class` results in `ByteArray`
- `#() class` results in `Array`
- `{} class` also results in `Array`

So apparently the latter two produce Arrays while the first produces a ByteArray. ByteArrays are what you would expect -- fixed sized arrays of bytes.

Now we'll have to figure out the difference between `#()` and `{}`. Try evaluating `#(a b c)`, it results in `#(#a #b #c)`; however when you try to evaluate `{a b c}`, it doesn't work (because `a` is not defined). The working version would be `{#a. #b. #c}`, which also results in `#(#a #b #c)`.

The difference between `#()` and `{}` is, that the first takes a list of Symbol names separated by spaces. You're also allowed to omit the `#` signs. Using this notation you can only create Arrays that contain Symbols. The second version is the generic Array literal. It takes any expressions, separated by `.` (dots). You can even write things like `{1+2. anyObject complexOperation}`.

This could lead you to always using the `{}` notation. However, there are some things to keep in mind: The moment of object creation differs: While `#()` Arrays are created during compilation, `{}` Arrays are created during execution. Thus when you run code with an `#()` expression, it will also return the *same* Array, while `{}` only returns *equal* Arrays (as long as you are using equal contents). Also, AFAIK the `{}` is not necessarily portable because it's not part of the ST-80 standard.

Comment: In other words the last paragraph says that using `{}` carries a potential performance hit.

Comment: Yes. Also see Martin Kobetic's answer which corrects a few inaccuracies in mine.

Comment: in other words, a #() array is literal created at compile time , and never changes, while {} syntax creates a new Array instance at run time and fills its elements by evaluating code for each element.So it is actually a syntax sugar for:
{ 1. 2. 3. } <=> Array with: 1 with: 2 with: 3.

Answer (score 17):

There's a bit of terminological confusion in Michael's answer, `#()` is a literal array whereas `{}` is not. A literal array is the one created by the compiler and can contain any other literal value (including other literal arrays) so the following is a valid literal array:

```
#(1 #blah nil ('hello' 3.14 true) $c [1 2 3])
```

On the other hand {} is merely a syntactic sugar for runtime array creation, so `{ 1+2. #a. anObject}` is equivalent to:

```
(Array new: 3) at: 1 put: 1 + 2; at: 2 put: #a; at: 3 put: anObject; yourself
```